# dynamically Adding and removing elements based on checkbox values with DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox

I'm just trying to dynamically add to a div within a form depending on which checkboxes are checked. So, I am creating the li tag and then they are added as `li` elements within an `ol` parent element so its just a list of values. I do not know what is wrong with my code, I'm not sure how to remove the appropriate value if the relevant checkbox is unchecked, and when I uncheck and then recheck a checkbox, it keeps adding the value over and over again.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <style>
    input {
      margin: 18px;
    }

    #o {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .u {
      list-style: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="width: 700px">

  <div style="float: left; width: 340px; height: 250px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 20px 0 10px 20px;">
      
      <form id="myForm">
        <ul class="u">
          <li><input id="showAlert1" type="checkbox" name="thing" value="laptop">laptop</li>
          <li><input id="showAlert2" type="checkbox" name="thing" value="iphone">iphone</li>
        </ul>
      </form>

  </div>

  <div id="myDiv" style="float: right; width: 317px; height: 250px; border: solid black; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0; padding: 20px 0 10px 20px;">
  <ol id="o">
    
  </ol>
  </div>
<script>

  document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('change', function () {

    var a = document.getElementsByName('thing');
   
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i].checked){
          createDynamicElement();
      } else if (!a[i].checked){
          removeDynamicElement();
      }
    } 

      function createDynamicElement(){
        var node = document.createElement("LI");
          node.setAttribute("id1", "Hey");
          var textnode = document.createTextNode(event.target.nextSibling.data);
          node.appendChild(textnode);
          document.getElementById("o").appendChild(node);
      }

      function removeDynamicElement() {
        document.querySelector("#o li").innerHTML = "";
      }

  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are adding an event listener to the form instead of the input elements themselves. I dont think the change event will be fired when an input element in a form changes. (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

On your event listener, try targeting the input elements themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
} else if (!a[i].checked){
      removeDynamicElement();
}

...
function removeDynamicElement() {
    document.querySelector("#o li").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Will empty the first or all matches(not sure) but wont remove them. Instead you should give li tags a unique ID and remove them completely via something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].checked){
      console.log(a[i])
      createDynamicElement(a[i].value);
  } else if (!a[i].checked){
      removeDynamicElement(a[i].value);
  }
}

  function createDynamicElement(id){
      var node = document.createElement("LI");
      node.setAttribute("id", id);
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(id);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      console.log(node)
      document.getElementById("o").appendChild(node);
  }
  function removeDynamicElement(id) {
    var target = document.getElementById(id)
    target.parentElement.removeChild(target);
  }
```

Or you could clear the ol completely on every change and repopulate it again like:

```
var a = document.getElementsByName('thing');
document.getElementById("o").innerHTML = null;

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].checked){
      console.log(a[i])
      createDynamicElement(a[i].value);
  }
}

  function createDynamicElement(id){
      var node = document.createElement("LI");
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(id);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      console.log(node)
      document.getElementById("o").appendChild(node);
  }
```

Edit:

A proper FIFO solution:

```
var a = document.getElementsByName('thing');

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var target = document.getElementById(a[i].value);
  if (a[i].checked && !target){
      createDynamicElement(a[i].value);
  } else if ((!a[i].checked) && target){
      removeDynamicElement(a[i].value);
  }
}

  function createDynamicElement(id){

      var node = document.createElement("li");
      node.setAttribute("id", id);
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(id);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      document.getElementById("o").appendChild(node);

      console.log("a")
  }
  function removeDynamicElement(id) {
    target.parentElement.removeChild(target);
  }

});
```

Comment: but I want to set sequence, when I checked laptop and iphone, then I unchecked laptop and again checked laptop, it should be print after iphone.

Comment: The problem was the for loop adding new elements without checking if the  li already exists in the OL.